# In akka-http how to get a List[HttpRequest] from a Route?

Tags: scala, akka-http

In `akka-http` since the following

```
case HttpRequest(GET, Uri.Path("/ping"), _, _, _) =>
        HttpResponse(entity = "PONG!")
```

can also be written as

```
val route: Route = 
    path("ping") {
        complete("PONG!")
    }
```

Is it possible to get `Seq[HttpRequest]` given a `Route` ?

```
   //I'm looking for something like this function
    def toHTTPRequests(route: Route): Seq[HttpRequest] = ???
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how or why you would get a collection of `HttpRequest` out of your http route.

If it helps, Akka-Http converts your `Route` to a function `HttpRequest => Future[HttpResponse]` , by calling `Route.asyncHandler(route)`.

Knowing this should help understanding/visualising what a `Route` really is. Picture it as an asynchronous channel: you feed it requests on one side, and responses come out from the other side.

More info [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/overview.html).